# Padding zeros on mulesoft

Tags: mule, padding, datamapper, dataweave

Im just wondering if it is possible to issue a format string using datamapper/dataweave to have a fixed length on a number and have padded zeros to complete the length?

something like

String.format("%056", variable_number);

I tried this on datamapper but it doesnt work. anything I missed?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

D,

In dataweave, you can simply format the number like -

```
data: 5 as :string {format:"00000"}
```

This will output `00005`. Number will be padded with 0 if original length is less than number of 0's.
eg. `123` -> `00123`.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Hi Manik, Im still not getting the padded version. Its a string to string mapping, not sure if it matters. 'BaleNumber: bale.ns0#BaleNumber as :string {format:"00000"}'

Comment: @PaulD. If your input is string the covert that to number first 'data: ('5' as :number) as :string {format: '00000'}'

Comment: Parenthesis are not even needed ;)

Answer (score 3):

To accommodate this requirement, then call [Global MEL Functions from DataWeave](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/using-dataweave-in-studio#calling-global-mel-functions-from-dataweave-code).

**Global MEL function:**

```
<configuration doc:name="Configuration">
    <expression-language>
        <global-functions>
            def zeroPad(variable_number) {
                String.format("%05d", variable_number);
            }
        </global-functions>
    </expression-language>
</configuration>
```

**DataWeave script:**

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/json
---
{
    result: zeroPad(123)
}
```

Comment: Hi sulthony I tried this solution but it was hanging when im using the debugger. It still produce the non padded string

Answer (score 0):

I had similiat requirement and accomplished t by first converting to string as using format with zeros.

The answer given above works
data: 5 as :string {format:"00000"}

If for some reason you cannot do it with dataweave operators you can do it by writing global functions using java libraries and calling them from dataweave.

Answer (score 0):

In Dataweave simply define like

```
Field: "12" as :number {format: "0000"}
```

The output will be like `0012`